# Postgresql as clustered role in Windows Failover Cluster

Tags: postgresql, clustering, windows-server

I am looking to implement a Highly available postgres cluster with automatic failover in a 2 node Windows cluster.

Can we configure it similar to active passive SQL Server FCI with shared storage disks.

Does open source Postgres is windows cluster aware and supports the solution? Is it recommended for PROD and what are the steps to configure it as a Failover cluster role.

If tis is not a supported solution, is there a solution available for HA postgres with automatic failover in windows nodes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is too general. However, PostgreSQL is certainly not Windows Cluster aware. You'll have to teach PostgreSQL awareness to Windows Cluster.

Comment: Thank You Laurenz. I am looking for high level steps to complete the setup and test , but i am not getting it in postgres documentaion or in internet. In SQL Server i can install SQL in active node and add the passive node to the FCI, but how should i install postgres on both the nodes with the data directory on a shared disk.